# ffmpeg Limit File Size

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I am converting MPGs into GIF files using ffmpeg.  I need to limit the output to 2MB max as this is the maximum GIF size supported on the server.  I have tried the -fs switch, however this chops off the video to fit the size.  I would rather have the GIF scaled and the quality adjusted.  The source videos are limited to 5 seconds, so I'm not trying to fit a video with particularly long duration into a small GIF file size.  Some solutions I have seen include checking the file size after conversion, deleting if too large and trying again with modified properties until the desired file size is reached.  Is there a more automated approach I could take with ffmpeg?

Comment: stop doing this, GIF is really not effective for video, _especially_ after it's damaged by MPEG-like artifacts. **Use WebM instead of GIF.**

Comment: GIF is a requirement for the product.

Comment: Yes, it's old but WebM doesn't work natively in iOS, so that's a non solution.  There's a reason GIFs are so wildly popular and supported by the big players.

Comment: You may deem it "useless", however ignoring the close-to 1B iOS devices isn't an effective business strategy.

Comment: Until then I'll support Apple devices.